# Variable Equality Breakpoint not-working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am working on Python and I am passing a parameter named `id` to my fucntion and i want to pause the execution for debugging purpose (check the value of response) if and only if the value of id is equal to '586982'.

[image]

But the execution is getting paused for all values of id irrespectively of `==` and `=`.

I tried the following cases:

1. id = 586982
2. id == 586982
3. id = "586982"
4. id == "586982"

I tried to find a solution but i am not getting any.

**Note: I changed variable name since `id` is a built in keyword in python but its still not working**

Comment: then update your question with the new "not-working" case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple reproduction and didn't encounter this problem.

After you entered the expression, you have to press **Enter** to save the breakpoint.

For example:

[image]

Comment: I swear yesterday i tried and it did not happen but today it is getting saved. Whatever. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `id` is an int, the condition should be written: `id == 586982` . If it is a string : `id == "586982"` .

However, `id` is normally a python function used to get the identifier of an object: `id(your_object)`. I am guessing that you have overridden it, which is not a good practice. There is likely somewhere in your code something like: `id = some_text_or_some_int` .

Comment: I changed the variable name but its still not working